# Checkout loader stuck

Tags: checkout, javascript, onepage-checkout, magento-2.1.1

In checkout page loader stuck and spinning forever. There are no js errors in console. HTML of spinner looks like this

```
<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
    <div class="loader">
        <img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>"
             alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Loading...'); ?>"
             style="position: absolute;">
    </div>
</div>
```

File **checkout-loader.js** looks like this

```
define([
'rjsResolver'
], function (resolver) {
'use strict';

/**
 * Removes provided loader element from DOM.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} $loader - Loader DOM element.
 */
function hideLoader($loader) {
    $loader.parentNode.removeChild($loader);
}

/**
 * Initializes assets loading process listener.
 *
 * @param {Object} config - Optional configuration
 * @param {HTMLElement} $loader - Loader DOM element.
 */
function init(config, $loader) {
    resolver(hideLoader.bind(null, $loader));
}

return init;
});
```

I tried `console.log` on `init()` function and it works, but not in `hideLoader()` function - so it is not called.

Also site using **IWD_Opc extension**.

Can you please give a hint where to look up the error

---

**UPDATE**

Here is some dirty fix that works for me.
I added line

```
resolver($loader.parentNode.removeChild($loader));
```

to init() function in checkout-loader.js

and line

```
$(document).find(blockLoaderClass).remove();
```

to removeBlockLoader() function in block-loader.js

Comment: The loader is most of times called for ajax calls.
So could you check if there are any ajax calls made and what response it gets.

Comment: It's magento checkout so there are dozens of ajax calls going on

Comment: did you try to disable the IWD_Opc  extension? Because i am curious if the extension is the cause

Comment: @Anna I applied your dirty fix only on block-loader.js and it works leaving the spinner during page loading. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while ago, it was caused by someone removing `data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'` inside `app/design/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml`

The div for the checkout loader should look similar to this:

```
<div id="checkout-loader" data-role="checkout-loader" class="loading-mask" data-mage-init='{"checkoutLoader": {}}'>
```

---

No idea if this could be the case for you but it's worth a look. If this isn't the case it's worth debugging the checkoutLoader JS.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this issue on my Magento 2.2.2.

If you have console error with `js-translation.json`, create `js-translation.json` with `{}` in `pub/static/frontend/{vendor}/{name}/{lanuguage}/`.

This fixed my Magento 2 in developer mode (in production mode `js-translation.json` is generated automatically)

It's curious that We've developed whole previous project on 2.1.x with `js-translation.json` error throughout and it had 0 effect on functionalities during development.